# BTA16 (snubless version) triac was killed with 02 laptop adapter, please advice on how to overcome!

Tags: triac, adapter, laptop

I found some threads asking on inductive load for triac can kill the triac with over clamping voltage, however, the thread is no longer open so let's me make a question here with a hope that the community would be so kind to to help.

I use a BTA16-600BRG with MOC3020. I make a test with normal resistive load and it worked fine with even 5A for short while without heatsink. Tests with fans, drilling tools were also fine. However, when I plug in 2 laptop adapters, the triac dead upon 1 (one) switch off and T1 and T2 become always connected (replacement of another Triac makes the relay work again and I test again with 2 adapter and the BTA16-600B got killed again).

The datasheet of the BTA tells that this is a snnubless triac. But it seems that the internal protection is not enough. In this case do I have to make a snnubber circuit for the BTA and how much would be the value for C and R.

Note: My actual PCB has no BC 547 as it not needed, I drive triac with MOC3020 only. I replace the dead BTA16 with a new one and it work again (of course, I dont want to try a test with 2 adapters again). My concern it: What was the problem that cause triac to die?
Thank you very much for your attention.
[image: Here is my schematic:]

I revised the schematic with [image: following additions] but have not tested yet!

Comment: Overvoltage does not damage triac but cause it on without gate current. Overheating damage. I had same issue and blame triac quality.

Comment: Now my BTA16 is on at all time even turn off power. So the problem is the low quality triac? I bought it from China and I think they are not snnubless as mentioned in datasheet!

Comment: I bought a few for low price from China and had same problem. It is may guess. Kill triac is not easy. Check the datasheet. Overvoltage cause triac on. It can hold over current for some time.

Comment: Snubber is not for overvoltage protection, it is for compensating some  current, so triac can act properly.

Comment: Thank you,
My schematic is:
MOC3021 (pin 6,4) >> BTA16 triac(Gate connected with T2 via a 330 ohm) 

Recommendations from here makes me feel that my schematic is wrong
https://www.edaboard.com/threads/bt136-triac-and-snubber-circuit-questions.225743/post-969638
I connected the gate with T2 instead of T1
Please adviced, I am a newbie in this world!

Comment: As source use the datasheet. Resistor 330 Ohm is OK.

Comment: In your schematic is not clear how the load connected. Triac supposed to be connected in serial with load.

Comment: That's right, I connect load via the triac as a switch and it worked fine (for months with lamp/resistive load switching) until I plugged in 02 laptop adapters (Dell and HP) to test high power inductive load and my triac BTA have A1 and A2 always connected (even without power).
AC terminal (N/L) >> Load (wire 1) >> pin 1 (on the schematic) >> triac >> pin 2 >> load(wire 2) >> Ac terminal (L/N)

Comment: _"I bought it from China"_ - big mistake. Don't buy any power device from China if you need it to be what it says it is!

Comment: Actually, living beside a big neighbor like China, the only thing we can do it to find a way to live with it. What I would like to ask here is: what would be the reason that causes the death of the triac?

Comment: The charger has a large capacitive load which can stress the Triac current with losses. Adding a choke might mitigate that carefully designed.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Tony,
Can you advice me on the following with thanks:
Expectation: I would like to make a relay with BTA16 to replace coil relay (SONGLE as an example as they created noise). Can it be possible with curent setting: Opto + BTA16 triac and no snnubed circuit (RC and/or Choke). expected output is up to 500W/220VAC/50Hz? I have tested the relay with drilling tool/ fans and they all worked well.
I would like to do this as I my purpose is to make a small relay to control lamp/small fans and magnetic contactor, not to power laptop adapter as in my test case.
Thanks for your attention!

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75  According to spec normally triac can deal with current bigger than nominal for one half cycle (20 ms). This days almost everything made in China. It is quality control matter. That things looks pretty authentic, but possible somebody sells goods not passed QC.

Comment: Thanks user263983 for your response! I am trying to look for a safe schematic for a relay that can handle well 2A 220VAC/50Hz without heatsink. I tested the above schematic with 2x240W Incandescent  lamp and the BTA16 (provided by Chinese) heat up to 45 degree celcious and stayed stably at that temperature. 
As it was an initial achievement, I deciced to use this to develop switching module for home lamps and low wattage device. 
Unluckily, the test failed with 2 laptop adapter (about 350W totally). Please advice me on what needed for fixing the relay with thanks!

Comment: Bay triac from reputable seller. Price may be  higher. SSR for 2A is available too.